# LINQ lambda for counting number of sequences

Tags: c#

I have the sample student data as follows:

```
ExamDate           Test           Result
01/21/2017         Math           Pass 
06/02/2017         Science        Pass
05/31/2018         Math           Fail
06/28/2018         Science        Pass 
07/03/2018         Math           Pass 
07/19/2018         Science        Fail *
08/01/2018         Math           Fail 
09/13/2018         Science        Fail *
09/15/2018         Math           Fail 
10/01/2018         Science        Fail *
12/15/2019         Math           Pass 
10/11/2019         Science        Fail *
...
```

In the above sorting ExamDate, there is 4 consecutive Science fail tests mark by * or (4-1) = 3 Science sequential fails in a row. Similarly, there is 2 consecutive Math fail tests or 1 Math sequential fail.

```
How can I group above data using LINQ lambda into a format like below:
    Science: 4 consecutive fail tests or (4-1) = 3 sequential fails
    Math: 2 consecutive fail tests or (2-1) = 1 sequential fails
```

Need help LINQ syntax to count how many sequential consecutive fails each test (Math, Science) based on sorting exam date?

Comment: What if there is fail fail fail pass fail fail fail ? is that 6 or 3 & 3? please specify as you haven't included enough information

Comment: What kind of data structure is used to store values. DataTable or list of list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe what you are looking for, the assumption is it counts consecutive groups

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x.Test)
                .Select(x => new
                    {
                       x.Key,
                       Results = x.ChunkBy(p => p.Result)
                                  .Select(y => new { y.Key, Count = y.Count() })
                                  .Where(z => z.Count > 1)
                    });
foreach (var item in query)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Group key = {item.Key}");
   foreach (var inner in item.Results.Where(x => x.Key =="Fail"))
   {
      Console.WriteLine($" - {inner.Count} consecutive fail tests or ({inner.Count}-1) = {inner.Count-1} sequential fails ");
   }
}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/nFO7iK)

**Example Output**

Note: this is with a more complicated data set

```
Group key = Math
 - 2 consecutive fail tests or (2-1) = 1  sequential fails 
 - 2 consecutive fail tests or (2-1) = 1  sequential fails 
 - 2 consecutive fail tests or (2-1) = 1  sequential fails 
Group key = Science
 - 4 consecutive fail tests or (4-1) = 3  sequential fails 
 - 8 consecutive fail tests or (8-1) = 7  sequential fails 
 - 2 consecutive fail tests or (2-1) = 1  sequential fails
```

For this to work (and it needs to run in memory), I have borrowed a thread safe method from Microsoft here [Group results by contiguous keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-results-by-contiguous-keys). It's a little overkill and there are easier ways to achieve this, however this is a fairly iconic piece of code

**Extensions**

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> ChunkBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
      => source.ChunkBy(keySelector, EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default);


   public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> ChunkBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
   {
      const bool noMoreSourceElements = true;
      var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

      if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
         yield break;

      while (true)
      {
         var key = keySelector(enumerator.Current);    
         var current = new Chunk<TKey, TSource>(key, enumerator, value => comparer.Equals(key, keySelector(value)));

         yield return current;

         if (current.CopyAllChunkElements() == noMoreSourceElements)
            yield break;
      }
   }
}
```

**Helper Class**

```
public class Chunk<TKey, TSource> : IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
{

   private readonly ChunkItem _head;    
   private readonly object _mLock = new object(); 
   private IEnumerator<TSource> _enumerator;    
   private bool _isLastSourceElement;    
   private Func<TSource, bool> _predicate;    
   private ChunkItem _tail;

   public Chunk(TKey key, IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
   {
      Key = key;
      _enumerator = enumerator;
      _predicate = predicate;
      _head = new ChunkItem(enumerator.Current);
      _tail = _head;
   }

   private bool DoneCopyingChunk => _tail == null;

   public TKey Key { get; }

   public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
   {  
      var current = _head;

      while (current != null)
      {
         yield return current.Value;

         lock (_mLock)
            if (current == _tail)
               CopyNextChunkElement();

         current = current.Next;
      }
   }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
      => GetEnumerator();


   private void CopyNextChunkElement()
   {

      _isLastSourceElement = !_enumerator.MoveNext();
   
      if (_isLastSourceElement || !_predicate(_enumerator.Current))
      {
         _enumerator = null;
         _predicate = null;
      }
      else
         _tail.Next = new ChunkItem(_enumerator.Current);

      _tail = _tail.Next;
   }

   internal bool CopyAllChunkElements()
   {
      while (true)
         lock (_mLock)
         {
            if (DoneCopyingChunk)
               return _isLastSourceElement;

            CopyNextChunkElement();
         }
   }
   private class ChunkItem
   {
      public readonly TSource Value;
      public ChunkItem Next;

      public ChunkItem(TSource value)
      {
         Value = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My 10 cents:

Suppose this is your class:

```
        public class Student
        {
            public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }
            public string Test { get; set; }

            public bool Result { get; set; }

            public bool IsStarred { get; set; }
        }
```

and this is your data:

```
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2017, 01, 21), Test = "Math", Result = true, IsStarred = false },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2017, 06, 02), Test = "Science", Result = true, IsStarred = false },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2018, 05, 31), Test = "Math", Result = false, IsStarred = false },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 28), Test = "Science", Result = true, IsStarred = false },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2018, 07, 03), Test = "Math", Result = true, IsStarred = false },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2018, 07, 19), Test = "Science", Result = false, IsStarred = true },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2018, 08, 01), Test = "Math", Result = true, IsStarred = false },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2018, 09, 13), Test = "Science", Result = false, IsStarred = true },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2018, 09, 15), Test = "Math", Result = false, IsStarred = false },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2018, 10, 01), Test = "Science", Result = false, IsStarred = true },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 15), Test = "Math", Result = true, IsStarred = false },
            new Student { ExamDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 10), Test = "Science", Result = false, IsStarred = true }
        };
```

Then you can do this:

```
  var query = from student in students
            orderby student.ExamDate
            group student.Result by student.Test into g
            select new
            {
                Group = g.Key,
                Elements = g.OrderByDescending(p2 => p2)
            };
```

Comment: The result expectation should be added up all the number of sequential fails for each test.